# 8051 AT89C51 PSEN ALE pins, not to be used

Tags: microcontroller, pins, 8051

I am new to microcontroller programming, and am about to lay hands on the 8051 AT89C51.

I want to do some basic things like flashing LEDs, microcontroller to microcontroller data exchange etc.

I have no intention to use external memory or things like that. So, I have no work with the ALE or PSEN pins. I have learnt that in this case I have to connect the EA pin to VCC.

Now my question is, what do I do with the PSEN and ALE pin connections. Do I leave them unconnected, ground, or connect them to VCC?

Comment: You haven’t told us exactly which 8051 chip you’re using - there’s quite a few. Assuming the chip you’re using has internal flash, then psen and ale can be left unconnected. As to why you’d start with the 8051 in this day and age is beyond me. 20 years too late!

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention, edited the question. I'll be using AT89C51. It has flash EPROM.

Comment: I actually had previous knowledge of the intel x86 syntax. Seems like the 8051 is still used, and I wanted to stick to the CISC and as far as I had known, 8051 and all those intel things are CISC. Learning the 8051 seemed much easier and simpler to me, don't know about others. I wanted to know though, and actually, did some investigation, which would be better, 8051 or AVR. I would never do PIC. But did not get any significant clue as to which I should choose and why.

Comment: Learnt that the AVR is RISC and faster, instructions are simpler, but takes more memory. But the 8051 is CISC and instructions are more compact. Learning the 8051 might also help me in the future if I ever get engaged with microprocessors. So, chose the 8051 anyway. Speed is not a very significant factor for me at the moment also. Just wanted to get my work done quick (less study quicker project completion). However, I would be curious, it would be also very helpful to me, if anyone would give me a good comparison of the AVR and 8051.

Comment: And, hope you are right, I will be then leaving the ALE and PSEN pins unconnected. They are both outputs in my case, if I am right, so leaving unconnected should not be a problem hopefully. Will see. Thanks bro.

Comment: And would you tell kindly, why I should not have started with the 8051?

Comment: There’s no need ‘to hope’ that I am right. The datasheet for your device will confirm. As for your comparison of AVR vs 8051 there’s some very fast 8051s available. Probably the most compelling difference is C compiler support. AVR wins hands down. ARM would be the modern day 8051 equiv - multivendor support and a massive range of devices from very small to GHz speed. For example, last time i designed in an 8051 was 2003 and the AVR in 2006.

Comment: Oh. Great. Yeah yeah, I actually have some fascination about the assembly. As for the ARM, not much idea about that. I like the CISC anyway, and my aim is not heavy work. My targets are in the light range actually. So seems like my choice of the 8051 was good, though made somewhat on the go. Basic device, straightforward, and everyone seems to know it pretty well. Thanks for the insights bro.

Comment: I wouldn’t get too hung up in on CISC vs RISC - its sort of meaningless once you get to ARM as it has way more instructions than the 8051. Just thought of another compelling reason against 8051 - no onchip debug. At least not on the chip you’ve mentioned.

Comment: Don't listen to them. Many modern devices still use 8051 derivatives, and the architecture is easy to understand which makes it a good MCU to learn about.

Comment: I have used 80C51 for years, with a good simulator ... Also AT89Cx051 for little projects (clocks ...), even with ... Arduino.

Comment: Everyone has his own review. Anyway, thanks to everyone for the good insights. And, as to the main question, I left the pins unconnected, and it's working.

Answer (score 2):

> Now my question is, what do I do with the PSEN and ALE pin
> connections. Do I leave them unconnected, ground, or connect them to
> VCC?

Download the datasheet for the particular AT89C51 variant you have, and study it carefully. This should tell you everything you need to know.

PSEN and ALE are outputs, so connecting them to ground or Vcc would be a bad idea. ALE can be set to output at 1/6 the oscillator frequency, which you might find useful. It may also be used as the program pulse input (/PROG) during Flash programming - another reason not to tie it to a supply rail.

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But maybe grounding would also be almost same. Maybe connecting to VCC would also not make a difference. It's output anyway. And yeah, the 1/6 clock is a good thing. Anyway, for now I have no business with the PSEN and ALE pins, and the MC is working as desired and expected with the pins unconnected. So I am happy with them unconnected.

Comment: However, I did not find anything significant in the AT89C51 datasheet concerning the ALE and PSEN pin connections when not used. They just seemed to present that they are basically output pins. So, left them unconnected as the first suggestion comes to mind and as suggested here. It worked out fine, so, not concerned with the other options anymore for now.

Comment: Anyway, thanks.